# Spyware/Anti-malware software for only one user

Tags: malware

Is it possible to install a corporate anti-malware (sort of a spyware with various things blocked) app on one user profile only, without it having access to another admin user profile on the same Mac?

For example, if it's installed in /Users/User1/Applications folder, will the User2 have no impact on it?

Comment: "a corporate anti-malware" - which one? tbh I can't see this really working, as an anti-malware suite needs access to the entire machine, at admin level.

Comment: It also depends on a lot of things, especially what exactly the anti-malware suite does exactly. Does it have a name you can share?