# Security application access from a standard user to administrator user - can it be "sandboxed"?

Tags: macbook-pro, security, permission, user-account, accounts

I have an administrator user on a Macbook laptop. From the admin account I have created a standard user. On the standard user I have installed [Sophos](https://www.sophos.com/en-us) which had to have full disk access enabled for it to work.

Initially, I have thought that if I separate the two users (while one is a standard account and one an admin account), Sophos and its services will not have access in my admin (private) user account. But, logging back in to the admin user I can see the software running in my admin account, too.

My question is, can this somehow be contained to the standard account? This is a private laptop which I am using for work too, but for that reason I've separated the users hoping that I can still continue to use the admin/private account for private purposes without being concerned about Sophos/client company tracking my online activity and having access to all of the data on my laptop (on the admin user).

Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: Similar question:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/424417/119271. Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/312058/119271 for info regarding app installs globally vs single user

Comment: Thanks for the links @Allan. If I read it correctly, it means that I should have installed it in Users/user_name/Applications instead of the default Applications folder for it to be isolated to one user. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: Things like AV are generally systemwide.  Though, I’ve never used Sophos, I can’t speak to their installation procedd